# My dog is obsessed with getting inside my home

Tags: dogs, behavior, safety, psychology, chewing

My Belgium Malinois recently got extremely ill after, what we suspect, being bit by a spider. He recovered quickly after getting the right antibiotics. He is now obsessed with getting inside the house. Everytime we leave the house he tries to gain entry by chewing on the gate and wooden door and door frame. Our front door has a hole from all the chewing and he has even ripped the security gate out the wall. Tonight we got home and he started to chew on the window frame, ripped the frame apart and broke a window. We are at a loss. I am 8 months pregnant and can't go on like this.

Edit: He is allowed in our home when we are home, he sleeps inside. They are just outside when we are not at home, but it was previously never a problem for him to stay outside.
We have 2 Belgium Malinois,they have a big yard to play. We often take them for walks, do training and take them swimming.

Comment: For clearification: Your dog is no time allowed in your house? Or is he allowed with you but not if nobody is at home?

Comment: We need more information here. Was he allowed in the house prior to the spider bite? During recovery? Now? Have you consulted your veterinarian about the behavioral change? Has anything else changed in your household? Your neighborhood?

Comment: Clarification. He sleeps in the house and is always inside when we are home. He has never had a problem with staying outside if we aren't home, often chose to sleep outside instead of inside.

Comment: It *may* be a side effect. It's possible that the spider venom might have affected your dog's behavior. The venom has likely influenced your dog's brain.